# What is the best way to show data in a table in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tabular

I have written a program which takes data from a text file and displays it in a table style format.

Data from text file:

```
Jim,0.33
Dave,0.67
James,0.67
Eden,0.5
```

Formatted using the program:

```
Position | Name              |Score
-----------------------------------
1        |Dave               |0.67
2        |James              |0.67
3        |Eden               |0.5
4        |Jim                |0.33
```

Without importing Pandas / SQL etc is there a better way of displaying this data?

The code I have written is below:

```
from tkinter import *

def show():

    tempList= [['Jim', '0.33'], ['Dave', '0.67'], ['James', '0.67'], ['Eden', '0.5']]

    tempList.sort(key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)
    listBox.insert(END, "Position | Name      \t\t |Score\n")
    listBox.insert(END,"-----------------------------------")
    listBox.insert(END,"\n")

    for i in range(len(tempList)):
        listBox.insert(END,(i+1))
        listBox.insert(END,"\t |")
        listBox.insert(END,tempList[i][0])
        listBox.insert(END,"\t \t|")
        listBox.insert(END,tempList[i][1])
        listBox.insert(END,"\n")

scores = Tk() 
label = Label(scores, text="High Scores", font = ("Arial",30)).grid(row = 0, columnspan = 3)
listBox= Text(scores,width = 40)
listBox.grid(row = 1,column= 0, columnspan = 2)
showScores = Button(scores, text = "Show scores",width = 15, command = show).grid(row = 4, column = 0)
closeButton = Button(scores, text = "Close",width = 15, command = exit).grid(row = 4, column = 1)

scores.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could use a series of frames and labels to display the data.

Comment: You can also use a properly configured Treeview to show your tabular data.

Answer (score 24):

A `ttk.Treeview` without the tree part can be used to display a table:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(master, columns=('Position', 'Name', 'Score'), show='headings')
```

Then set the column labels with

```
tree.heading(<column>, text="Label")
```

and add rows with

```
tree.insert("", "end", values=(<position>, <name>, <score>))
```

The first argument is the item's parent, since you want a table, all items have the same parent, the root `""`. The second argument is the position of the new item in the tree.

Full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def show():

    tempList = [['Jim', '0.33'], ['Dave', '0.67'], ['James', '0.67'], ['Eden', '0.5']]
    tempList.sort(key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)

    for i, (name, score) in enumerate(tempList, start=1):
        listBox.insert("", "end", values=(i, name, score))

scores = tk.Tk() 
label = tk.Label(scores, text="High Scores", font=("Arial",30)).grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
# create Treeview with 3 columns
cols = ('Position', 'Name', 'Score')
listBox = ttk.Treeview(scores, columns=cols, show='headings')
# set column headings
for col in cols:
    listBox.heading(col, text=col)    
listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

showScores = tk.Button(scores, text="Show scores", width=15, command=show).grid(row=4, column=0)
closeButton = tk.Button(scores, text="Close", width=15, command=exit).grid(row=4, column=1)

scores.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

You can find more details about the `Treeview` widget [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190428233645/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
pt = Table(frame)
pt.show()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.