# Table like user interface in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

[Example of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWj5H.png)

Is there any way I can create a table like UI with Tkinter? Any widget or module?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the treeview, or you could build a lot of labels.

Comment: Treeview is a way, but idt there is a proper table widget for table, u can try listview too

Comment: You can try [tkintertable](https://pypi.org/project/tkintertable/) as well.

Comment: This is far too vague. How do you define "table"? Does it need to be editable? Do you need resizable columns? Do rows need to be able to have formula? Do cells need to support more than one line of text? Do they need to support images or other embedded widgets?

Comment: Example of table using a Treeview: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625306/what-is-the-best-way-to-show-data-in-a-table-in-tkinter/50651988#50651988

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a table in `tkinter`. It's highly dynamic and fluid. You can set `rows`, `columns`, `columnspan`, `rowspan`, and more. The best part is: it's built right into the `root` and `Frame`. You can access it via [.grid()](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), and configure it via `.grid_rowconfigure()` and `.grid_columnconfigure()`