# Creating a Data Table as a widget on Python Tkinter

Tags: python, math, tkinter

I´m developing an app that takes raw data, makes some operations on it and the returns the results on a table.
To make this, i have created a series of functions but i can´t get to the final step which is presenting the results in a table.

The final table has 11 rows and 1 column.

I have tried creating classes and functions to achieve the expected result but I can´t seem to achieve it.

I´ll show you the last try:

```
def Tabula(total_rows,total_columns,datos): 
rows = []
for i in range(total_rows):
    cols = []
    for j in range(total_columns):
        e = Entry(window)
        e.grid(row=datos[i,:], column=datos[:,j], sticky=NSEW)
        cols.append(e)

    rows.append(cols)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348264/does-tkinter-have-a-table-widget or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625306/what-is-the-best-way-to-show-data-in-a-table-in-tkinter?

Comment: yes I have, but I can't seem to adapt those answers to my problem or they just don't work.

Comment: But what does not work? This is quite unprecise to say " I can´t seem to achieve it." or "they just don't work". If you transformed your current code snippet into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would make clearer what is the issue.  I really don't see what is the issue with creating a `ttk.Treeview` and inserting 11 rows of data in it, which is a straightforward way to create a data table in tkinter.