# tkinter.ttk treeview does not seem to recognize column names as created

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm having a vexing problem trying to use ttk.Treeview to display data from a file. I never actually get to the data part of the job because I cannot seem to set up the Treeview structure.

For Reasons, I want to create the Treeview columns from a list of column names which, in turn, I get from a tuple of tuples holding structure info. Creating the columns seems to work okay, as demonstrated by this test program. But when I try to create headings for the columns, I get a message saying that the column names I've assigned are not recognized as identifiers.

That's despite this from the documentation:

> Column identifiers take any of the following forms:
>
> - A symbolic name from the list of columns option.
> - An integer n, specifying the nth data column.
> - A string of the form #n, where n is an integer, specifying the nth display column.

I trolled countless example and tutorial and reference pages on this -- it's a basic Treeview operation, but they all seem to say that what I'm doing should work. It does not. What is wrong?

This is using python 3.9.4 in a linux system, with tkinter version 8.6.10.

Here is a test program:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk as ttk

# list of data fields and column widths
field_reference = (('DateTime', 20),
                   ('Rate',10),
                   ('Amp1',15),
                   ('Amp2',15),
                   ('Residual',20))

#create a tkinter app
app = Tk()
app.title("Treeview Demo") 
app.geometry('700x400+100+100')
app.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
app.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# create a frame holding a treeview 
fileDataFrame = ttk.Frame(app, padding="3 3 12 12")
fileDataFrame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
fDF_Title = ttk.Label(fileDataFrame, text="Data")
fDF_Title.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W, N))

# set up treeview for the data tree
fileDataTree = ttk.Treeview(fileDataFrame, show='headings')
# specify a column for each of the fields in the data file
column_list=[]
for item in field_reference:
    column_list.append(item[0])

fileDataTree.columns = column_list

fileDataTree.heading('#0',text='')

print("At line 38 fileDataTree columns are: {}".format(fileDataTree.columns))

for item in field_reference:
    fileDataTree.heading(item[0], text=item[0])
    fileDataTree.column(item[0], width=item[1])

fileDataTree.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='W,N')    

app.mainloop()
```

Which outputs this:

```
At line 38 fileDataTree columns are: ['DateTime', 'Rate', 'Amp1', 'Amp2', 'Residual']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/src/tkinter/./demo_ttktree.py", line 41, in <module>
    fileDataTree.heading(item[0], text=item[0])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/tkinter/ttk.py", line 1299, in heading
    return _val_or_dict(self.tk, kw, self._w, 'heading', column)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/tkinter/ttk.py", line 298, in _val_or_dict
    res = tk.call(*(args + options))
_tkinter.TclError: Invalid column index DateTime
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You did not set the `columns` option of `Treeview`.

Comment: You can find an example of how to create a treeview with columns [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50651988/6415268)

Comment: acw1668 -- Isn't that done by this line: fileDataTree.columns = column_list

Comment: j_4321: Yes, that example does the same thing I do, except that it initially declares the columns in the creation of the treeview, whereas I do it by assigning a list to treeview.columns. The latter should work, shouldn't it? When I print out the value of columns it seems correct.

Comment: `fileDataTree.columns` is an attribute, not option.  Use `fileDataTree['columns']` instead.

Comment: acw1668: Ah, okay, I see. Assigning a list to the non-existent attribute 'columns' simply created the attribute without causing an error. That's what threw me off. That and the somewhat elliptic nature of the documentation. Thanks!