# Python GUI display row level header details

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I would like to display information in tabular form where each row contains field and value details.

```
**Field**|**Value**\n
Field1  value1\n
Field2  value2\n
Field3  value3\n
Field4  value4\n
Field5  value5\n
Field6  value6\n
Field7  value7\n
Field8  value8\n
Field9  value9\n
Field10 value10\n
.   .
.   .
.   .
.   .
.   .
Field150    value150
```

[image: display example]

I tried Python Tkinter treeview but it takes header information in column-wise. I'd like to know if there is any widget or any way where I can display treeview where header is at low level.

Any suggestions pls?

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz0YJ.png)

Comment: What do you mean by *"header is at low level"*?  Does it mean that you don't want to show the header at all?

Comment: basically need Treeview like structure with first column as header details and column 2, 3 4 ..as values

ex:

Field Value
Field1 value1
Field2 value2
..

Comment: I don't understand why the `Treeview` does not correspond to what you want. The picture is very similar to the table in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50651988/6415268) which is done with a treeview.

Comment: Trreeview insert records at rowlevel. Where header is at first row ( column header ). I am looking for transpose of Treeview structure where heading is at first column and values and 2nd, 3rd column .. so on

Comment: Can you reconstruct the data source so that you can insert them row by row? Also better provide sample data as well.