# Center text in table Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, treeview

Here is my code to fetch data from MySQL and present it by a table. But because I am a newbie, I don't really understand about TreeView. Hence I don't know how to center the text in table. (Sorry because of inserting this picture because when I paste the code, it cannot be shown in correct format).

You can find similar lines of code here (in comment section): [What is the best way to show data in a table in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625306/what-is-the-best-way-to-show-data-in-a-table-in-tkinter)
[image]

Here is my table generated: (The text is on the left side of columns).
[image]

Thank all of you so much!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. The code isn't searchable or copyable, and the visually impaired can't see it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `anchor` for the `column` of `Treeview`:

```
for col in columns:
    listBox.heading(col,text=col,anchor='center')
    listBox.column(col,anchor='center')
```

Don't name your `Treeview` as `listBox`, there is another widget called `Listbox` too.

Read more about treeview: [45. ttk.Treeview](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html)