# Python: display data from Access table with Tkinter

Tags: python, ms-access, tkinter

I'm new to Python.
I'd like to load same data from an Access Table into a window created by Tkinter.

The code I'm using to extract data is this

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=<path to database>.ACCDB;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from <table>')
   
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

that of course is good just to extract data from the table
So my question is: how can I import an Access table in Python and show in a Tkinter window?
Thank you for helping
Regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If your question is how to display data in table with tkinter, you can start by having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348264/does-tkinter-have-a-table-widget, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625306/what-is-the-best-way-to-show-data-in-a-table-in-tkinter